# React onDrop event conflict with French characters

Tags: reactjs

We are using react-dropzone library and using the onDrop event from it
https://react-dropzone.js.org/

I need to upload files with the react onDrop event. The problem is that some French characters are causing problems.

It's a .png file and the problem comes from the name "Capture d'écran". When I change the name to plain English it works properly.

in the onDrop event I wrote
`onDrop{files => console.log(files)}`

In the case with Capture d'écran I receive this in the console:
[image]

In the case with the English characters I receive this in the console:
[image]

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks!